# Unable to make a dynamic listview of scrolltype horizontal?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I am making a map app with listview items of places that will be marked for now I want to make an array of listview to make sure it is dynamic and not hardcoded.

I am new in the widget world of flutter. The more the data will be from the server the more listview items should be added. Here is the code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:donation_yoga/services/json_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

import 'AddData.dart';

//import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  /* Getting Live Location */
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();

  void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLngPos = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        CameraPosition(target: latLngPos, zoom: 15.0);

    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          myLayoutWidget(),
          // _buildContainer(),
          _createForm(context),
          listWidget1(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myLayoutWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          locatePosition();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget listWidget1() {
  Centres centre;
  return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: centre.entries.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return _boxes(
          centre.entries[index],
          centre.latitudes[index],
          centre.longitudes[index],
          centre.centres[index],
        );
      });
}

Widget _boxes(String _image, double lat, double long, String restaurantName) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      child: new FittedBox(
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 14.0,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
            shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 180,
                  height: 200,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                    child: Image(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: NetworkImage(_image),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: listWidget1(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _createForm(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment(-0.8, -0.08),
    child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddData()),
          );
        },
        child: Text("Create")),
  );
}
```

It displays nothing on screen except of course the maps I have commented the following which was working but was hardcoded.

```
/*
Widget _buildContainer() {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 150.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: _boxes(
                "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipO3VPL9m-b355xWeg4MXmOQTauFAEkavSluTtJU=w225-h160-k-no",
                40.738380,
                -73.988426,
                Centres.first),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: _boxes(
                "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMKRN-1zTYMUVPrH-CcKzfTo6Nai7wdL7D8PMkt=w340-h160-k-no",
                40.761421,
                -73.981667,
                Centres.second),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: _boxes(
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504940892017-d23b9053d5d4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                40.732128,
                -73.999619,
                Centres.third),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}


Widget myDetailsContainer1(String restaurantName) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
        child: Container(
            child: Text(
          restaurantName,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff6200ee),
              fontSize: 24.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
      Container(
          child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              child: Text(
            "4.1",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          )),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStar,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.solidStarHalf,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              child: Text(
            "(946)",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black54,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          )),
        ],
      )),
      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
      Container(
          child: Text(
        "This is ",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54,
          fontSize: 18.0,
        ),
      )),
      SizedBox(height: 5.0),
      Container(
          child: Text(
        "Closed \u00B7 Opens 17:00 Thu",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      )),
    ],
  );
}
*/
```

Here is my Centres class which contains the list of items, this will come from https send/receive requests in flutter later on.

```
class Centres {
  final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
  final List<String> centres = [
    'first location',
    'second location',
    'third location'
  ];
  final List<double> latitudes = [40.732128, 40.732128, 40.732128];
  final List<double> longitudes = [-73.999619, -73.999619, -73.999619];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
//import 'package:donation_yoga/services/json_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

import 'AddData.dart';

//import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  /* Getting Live Location */
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();

  void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLngPos = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        CameraPosition(target: latLngPos, zoom: 15.0);

    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          myLayoutWidget(),
          _createForm(context),
          
          _buildContainer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myLayoutWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          locatePosition();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _boxes(String _image, double lat, double long, String restaurantName) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      child: new FittedBox(
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 14.0,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
            shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 180,
                  height: 200,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                    child: Image(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: NetworkImage(_image),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: _buildContainer(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildContainer() {
  final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
  final List<String> centres = [
    'first location',
    'second location',
    'third location'
  ];
  final List<double> latitudes = [40.732128, 40.732128, 40.732128];
  final List<double> longitudes = [-73.999619, -73.999619, -73.999619];
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 150.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: centres.asMap().entries.map((element) {
          int index = element.key;
          return Column(children: [
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: _boxes(
                  "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipO3VPL9m-b355xWeg4MXmOQTauFAEkavSluTtJU=w225-h160-k-no",
                  latitudes[index],
                  longitudes[index],
                  element.toString()),
            ),
          ]);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _createForm(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment(-0.8, -0.08),
    child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddData()),
          );
        },
        child: Text("Create")),
  );
}
```

The Error is Stack Overflow see also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors